# ubuntu 14.04 - can't open display / could not open X display - Nvidia ( all versions)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have serious issues since I installed 14.04 on my machine.My graphics card is Nvidia geforce GTX 680. I have double Xeon processors machine. On previous Ubuntu 12.04 it worked nicely.

I've tried almost all versions of nvidia drivers avilable (from Nvidia website and open sources xorg-edgers/ppa) since a week and still no success.
All I can get is black screen and no even chance to switch to terminal.
The only possible use of Ubuntu is to use default nouveau drivers.
It can't detect my screen - when I press xrandr to add new mode it says : can't open display :0.0
When i press xdiagnose it says : could not open X display.

Any workarounds anybody ?

Comment: I am having the same issue with a 8800GTS 320 card. I had no issues until recently. There must be some update that broke something, but I have found no work around presently. Wasted three days so far trying to find a solution.